# Windows Service An exception occurred during a WebClient request

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-services

I receive the following error from a Windows Service application

```
   System.Net.WebException = {"An exception occurred during a WebClient request."}
    -2146233079
    InnerException = {"Configuration system failed to initialize"}
```

**The same code on a Console application works fine.**

The Service file has not setup Security on "Local Service" (in my test environment)

Could you point me out what could cause the error and how to solve it?

```
    Try
        Using client As New Net.WebClient
            Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
            reqparm.Add("DeviceId", deviceId)
            reqparm.Add("StatusCode", statusCode)
            reqparm.Add("Type", "printer")
            reqparm.Add("Message", msg)
            Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues("http://xxx.xxx.com/api/notification", "POST", reqparm)
            Dim responsebody = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responsebytes)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'do nothing
    End Try
```

my App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <configSections>
    <section name="app" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <app>
    <add key="version" value="0.0.1"/>
  </app>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the App.config file. This the correct version, only one instance of `<configSections>` and should be the first element after `<configuration>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="app" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <app>
    <add key="version" value="0.0.1"/>
  </app>
</configuration>
```